# iPhone 3GS stuck in apple logo

Tags: itunes, restore, iphone

My friend owns an old iPhone 3GS(I know it's vintage) that entered a boot loop a couple of days after it was jailbroken. So how I tried tackling the problem was by performing a restore through iTunes(since it is the only way) but unfortunately that didn't work. I tried 5 different ipsw files and I even tried clicking on restore to allow iTunes to fetch the newest ipsw for me but still no luck. I tried using a different computer, still no luck. I even tried using an older version of iTunes since the iPhone 3GS's release but guess what, still no luck. Any ideas on how to tackle this problem and do you reckon the phone is **soft bricked** or **hard bricked**?

Answer (score 1):

Firm-Bricked I'm afraid. It happens a lot with those.